# ShowMessage() doesn't work for iOS 7 simulator in Delphi xe5

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

After installing update 1 and the iOS 7 styles for delphi xe5, the function, "ShowMessage('some text to show');" does not work properly. The function seems to execute fine in the debugger but within the simulator, no pop up message is shown. This is true for the dialog, alert confirmation features as well. Everything does work fine on an actual device...
Anyway to fix this so that it works again for the simulator ?

Comment: Agreed - I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43522 this is fixed in Delphi XE5 Update 2, available now (see [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29662))

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a known problem that still has not been fixed: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96373